# IntelliJ does not show project folders

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an issue with IntelliJ. It doesn't show any folders in my project view on the left. 
My setting is "View As: Project"
How can I manage it so that the folders and packages are shown again?
I don't have any clue because I didn't change any options!

I'm using IntelliJ 10.0.3. 
I am working on a Maven Lift Project.

Comment: So I'm working with Intellij version 14.1.5 and had a similar situation happen to me. I deleted all my project files (leaving just the idea folder), then fetched all code down fresh with git. Intellij didn't show any folders but did recognise the modules in project structure. I had to resolve all dependencies with maven, then open and close Intellij before the folders for all modules were shown in project view again.

Comment: i know there are solutions already provided. But this is how i got the issue in the first place. I was checking out the git project and before it finishes, opened the project in intellij. So the .idea folder was in a corrupt state and intellij does not refresh it automatically. Either you can delete the .idea folder and open again or try doing a synchronize. hope it helps.

Comment: The same thing happened to me after I deleted the `.idea` folder

Comment: IntelliJ Community 2018.1 - Simply deleting the entire .idea folder and then re-opening root folder from the IDE fixed this issue for me. IntelliJ rebuilt and reindexed the entire project.

Comment: I have remove git cloned folder. When I clone back my repository and open in IntelliJ it doesn't show the folders. So, after figure out I found `.idea` folder is missing `modules.xml` & `terrafuse.iml`. So, I copy this two files from `.idea` folder of another project and restarted the IntelliJ which in turn start working normally.

Comment: Still a bug in IntelliJ 2021.2

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816419/intellij-does-not-show-project-folders/69255837#answer-69255837

Comment: Small tip to JetBrains company - I had this issue around 6 times in 1 year.
So I pretty sure when it happen.
When for some reason Debugging process can not be finished correctly and connection stays open. After that you just close Idea -> and voila your .idea folder corrupted.

Comment: delete the .idea folder, followed by a repair IDE, then Reopen the project (from the IDE repair) worked out for me.

Answer (score 526, accepted):

So after asking another question, someone helped me figure out that under **File > Project Structure > Modules**, there's supposed to be stuff there. If it's empty (says "Nothing to show"), do the following:

1. In **File > Project Structure > Modules**, click the "+" button,
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (because weirdly it won't let me click on "New Module")
   [image: step 2]
3. In the window that pops up, click on the "..." next button which takes you to the Content root. Find your root folder and select it
   [image: step 3 part 1] [image: step 3]
4. Click the "ok" button
5. Ignore any warning that says the name is already in use

Comment: I had to import a module

Comment: This was 95% of the solution for me.  I had to "Add Content Root" on that screen.  Then for some reason all the folders magically appeared.

Comment: This is something that has always bothered me, when you make a new project from existing source, everything works great. But when you make a new project, IDEA is constantly "this file isn't part of the project...".  Now it all makes sense.

Comment: Had to select "java" and click on "next" in the 3rd step.

Comment: I can't believe how many times I have to do this with Intellij. Is there any way to get it to persist? I've got to  be doing something contrary to Intellij's intent, because existing projects helpfully do this to me periodically.

Comment: making a new module worked but importing from the same folder worked just as well.

Comment: Once you add a module you need to click on the "Source" tab select what you want to see in the IDE and mark it with the blue button "sources".

Comment: Because this is a asinine way to import files.

Comment: what if it is doing this 100% of the time, even with projects you just created an hour ago with intellij?

Comment: I had to reopen the project from the pom.xml and delete the existing project.

Comment: What about MVN project? Should I select the Maven instead of Java?

Comment: There is no "folder structure" under file

Comment: Beware, when doing this with a Node-Project, where you create something, like a React-App. It removes everything and even replaces the Git-Repository! So, do this only, when having your Git-Repo backed up on a remote server. (Restore with ``git fetch --all`` and ``git reset --hard origin/master``

Answer (score 587):

I had to quit Intellij and remove the `.idea` folder (I stashed it first, just in case). I then re-opened the project and that worked for me.
Don't forget to save your configuration (e.g. debug / run configurations) before that, because they will also be deleted.

Comment: I think it's still a bug in IDEA 1 year later?

Comment: I didn't know the mac equivalent of the accepted answer, so I tried this first and magically all is good now

Comment: Similar, but had to delete the <projectName>.iml file too.

Comment: Worked for me too. Better than creating a new module without a reason.

Comment: Been having this issue for YEARS, both windows and linux, never seems to be fixed

Comment: september 2017 checking in, it's still happening

Comment: This works!  Just make sure you close Intelli-j completely after deleting the .idea dir.  If you just close the project itself and reopen from the welcome screen the issue persists.

Comment: Still happening in Jan 2018

Comment: It's insane to me that this is still an issue for three years. Happens 1/3 times I open a JetBrains product, Mac or Linux. Deleting .idea works, but then I have to re-do all of my project settings.

Comment: Had this happen to a few times to me recently (last instance was an hour ago) , good to see that deleting .idea resolves it

Comment: The best solution I could found. In face I was using the Angular UI code and it was difficult for me to choose a type etc.

Comment: Still happening for IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 CE

Comment: Remote .idea directory and also remote files ends with .iml, .ipr .iws.

Comment: Yup. same. Deleted .idea and .iml, closed and reopened project and works.

Comment: Still there in 2021 Deleting .idea works like a charm!

Comment: Still happens often. Really annoying losing all configs..

Comment: Prremium priced IDE and it just happened to me in 2021.

Comment: rm -rf .idea && idea . (2021 still a bug)

Comment: Still happening in Rubymine ;) Deleting `.idea` did the trick. (2022)

Comment: after update IntelliJ i get this problem. Deleting .idea resolve it. (04/2022)

Comment: It is better to have .idea folder backup - just in case it happen again.

Comment: happening in 2023 :-) advise worked.

Comment: while this works I have to do it several times a week now.

Comment: yeah this issue is happening from my first usage which is 2012 to till date. you need to delete `.idea` folder to fix this

Comment: still a problem in 2024 year when using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2.
Fix is still working.

Comment: Still in 2024... :( yes deleting .idea directory worked. mac.

Comment: 2024-02-13 : will they ever fix this?

Comment: Still a thing in February 2024... Deleting .idea works like a charm

Answer (score 80):

I had this issue as well. 
It is something do with **.idea** just delete it and restart IntelliJ

Comment: rm -rf .idea &&
idea .  
(2021 still a bug)

Comment: @JorgeTovar + apt install vim :)

Comment: This should be considered as an answer, after deleting .idea, all project directories remain as it should be. Thanks @RMati

Answer (score 68):

I went to *File* → *Project Structure* → *Modules*, clicked on + and then *Import Module*, found my root folder, selected it and it worked.

For IntelliJ 14.

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS Intellij 2021.3.1

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS Intellij 2023.3.3
Legend!

Comment: Splendid! - nice and simple

Comment: This worked for me. I m using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.5 (Ultimate Edition)

Answer (score 45):

A lot of answers here suggest deleting `.idea`. this works for me only about 50% of the time. A simple restart works about 10% of the time. Re-adding things as a module is an awful hack that causes other issues like losing some project-only settings.

I've also found this solution to work:

1. File -> Repair IDE

[image]

2. A dialog shows in the bottom right. Click "Rescan Project indexes"

[image]

3. When the next dialog shows, click Reopen Project:

[image]

4. Directories should show now.

Comment: Problem is, this seems to not work wit Jetbrains Gateway in WSL. Repair Project just does nothing at all and the assistant won't launch

Comment: @MarianKlühspies I have noticed that the problem gets far worse in slow Virtual Machines. I used to run this in a Linux Mint VirtualBox setup because the company I worked at refused native Linux installs. The more my host machine struggled, the more often this problem occurred. I got into the habit of immediately just cancelling project loading during startup, and then reopening. Seems to help quite a bit. Maybe try preventing auto-loading previous sessions, then selecting what you need from the recents list after the application boots. I'd be interested to know if that helps

Answer (score 24):

I am a new user of IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2. I opened an existing project when I first ran the program and had the same issue whereby it only showed files in the root directory in the 1. Project panel, but not the project folders (expandable tree-like structure).

Initially, I tried going to Project Settings > Modules, where no modules were shown listed. I clicked (+), and tried to select my root folder, but it wouldn't select the folder.

So I then solved it with these steps instead:

- Exit IntelliJ
- Delete the existing .idea folder (i.e. `rm -rf .idea`)
- Restart IntelliJ
- Verified that the project root folder now appeared (in Project Settings > Modules)
- Toggle On the toolbar buttons (i.e. 1. Project Structure) to display on the left sidebar (clicked  **View > Toolbar Buttons** until tick appears)
- Click **1. Project Structure** toolbar button until its sidebar is revealed
- Click the arrow icon on the left of your project's root directory name that appears to expand the tree folder structure

UPDATE 2nd Sept 2017: If you've added a Module SDK and it added a `.iml` file within a subdirectory of the root of your project that causes it to load the module subdirectory, then it may be necessary for you to modify that `.iml` file by appending `/..` as shown below.

```
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/..">
```

Answer (score 23):

1. close intellij
2. delete .idea folder
3. restart intellij
4. click import, select your project
5. create project from existing sources, click next, next, next

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 20):

1. You **don't** have to quit Intellij completely to make this work. Simply **close** the project that you have open. (You can open any another project to avoid closing it completely)
2. Go to the directory where you have your project installed and delete the **".idea"** folder.
3. Reopen the Project.

That should fix it. It worked for me in May 2018.

Answer (score 19):

Try to re-import the Maven project. Also make sure that the project directory name is not excluded in `Settings | File Types | Ignore Files and Folders`.

Comment: I have the same problem (seen it twice today on different projects). But removing all entries from the "Ignore Files and Folders" setting, doesn't help. What do you mean "re-import"?

Comment: @BT try to delete `.idea` directory and create a new project on top of the existing files or import `pom.xml` if your project is Maven based. If the issue persists, please submit a ticket to the support team.

Comment: This happened to me - it's because I was switching branches and in this process I managed to exclude folders.

Answer (score 12):

Check out answer at

[Can't see project folders in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359018/cant-see-project-folders-in-intellij-idea/44272046#44272046)

It might be because the project didn't have any modules defined. Try adding existing source code by hitting File > New > Module from Existing Sources and select the parent directory of the project for source code[image]

Comment: In case it is an Eclipse project you can also go to File -> Project Structure... -> Modules -> + -> Import Module -> go to your project root folder and select the .profile from Eclipse (you may need to click the "eye" icon to show hidden files).

Answer (score 12):

Deleting `.idea/workspace.xml` worked for me. Close the project, delete `.idea/workspace.xml`, and open the project again. I was using version 2019.1.

Comment: Or just delete the whole .idea folder and open with IntelliJ again

Answer (score 12):

Change the "Project" dropdown to be "Project Files"

[image: IntelliJ Example]

If the files still have a yellow highlighting behind them you may need to follow the #2 answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28375299/3769076). The yellow highlighting indicates the files are not part of the project. You can remedy this by creating a module as explained in their answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me because Project Files shows all meta files as well, which is a messy workspace.

Answer (score 11):

I have deleted the .idea folder. Closed ItelliJ and restarted to open the same project.

It asked to add the content root. That worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I faced same issue when i deleted the .idea folder.

However, when I tried to invalidate and re-start, the .idea folder got created again but still the folders were not showing up.

I had to 1.close IntelliJ, 2.delete the .idea folder, 3.launch IntelliJ

This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 9):

1. Backup the `.idea` folder into a zip file
2. Delete `.idea` folder
3. Reopen the project
4. Close the project
5. Extract backup files into the new fresh generated `.idea` folder
6. Reopen the project
7. Praise the sun ☀️ `\[T]/`

Answer (score 9):

I used the IDE Repair feature in WebStorm, without deleting .idea, in order to get the folders to show again.

[image]

Comment: This does the job, though I needed to press the option to reindex the files 2 times without luck, then it prompted me to reopen the project and then it worked.

Comment: Wow, I was not expecting this to help, but did, thanks a lot!

Comment: Folks, _before_ you start messing with your `.idea` folder, please do yourself a favor and try this one!

Answer (score 8):

I have a better solution that worked for me and it might work for you. No need to delete the whole `.idea` folder as this way you lose the whole project.
It is possible that you just accidentally excluded all folders in project settings.
I also found that project folders disappeared. I was trying to find out how to disable indexing, so I was looking at Project Settings -> Modules and I clicked on Excluded to see if I could add the whole project there to ignore it for indexing. It didn't do anything and I couldn't drag and drop the folder under Excluded. What I didn't realize is that simply clicking "Excluded", IntelliJ automatically moves the folder to Excluded and all folders disappeared in Project Explorer. "Excluded" button changes background to gray, which means exclusion is active. This is a very poor user interface because it is hardly noticeable and clicking this button has a far-reaching impact on your project.

Fix:

1. Open Project Settings -> Modules
2. If Excluded is highlighted, click on it
3. Click Apply or Close

Result:
Folders in your project show up again

Really bad bad bad UI design! Source and Excluded buttons look like tabs when they work in fact as "Checkboxes"!

Be careful, just clicking Sources or Excluded seems like an innocent selection of tab without any visible effect, yet it has far-reaching consequences, basically adding or removing files from the build process.

Comment: This solution worked for me after the higher ranked answers did not. Seems like there is really more than one correct solution for this problem.

Answer (score 8):

for me removing the `.idea` folder from the project directory worked.

Comment: Repeating existing answers doesn't add value to the community.

Answer (score 7):

I have a nodeJs project and lost my folders after removing the /[project_name].iml file.

This restored the folders while preserving my other project settings:

- `Project Settings > Modules`
- `+ Add Content Root`

Answer (score 4):

Even after 5 years, and having some experience with idea, I still have this problem all the times. Here is the simplest solution.

- Close Idea
- Delete .idea
- Start Idea and `open project` instead of `import project`

And then, open conf file for your framework, like `pom.xml` or `build.sbt` or `build.gradle` etc and it will automatically prompts to `import project` and when you click and when it finishes, your project is mostly setup correct.

Comment: but if you delete the .idea folder you loose all the project specific configurations

Comment: Yes, we loose any specific project settings, but most of the module settings can be recovered if you open `pom.xml` or `build.sbt` and use import project feature.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the `.idea` folder wasn't enough for me.

This seemed to originated from some git issue.

I had to

1. Close PyCharm
2. Add `**/.idea` to `.gitignore`
3. Delete the `.idea` folder
4. Open PyCharm

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem after an upgrade from intellij 15 (v143) to 2016.3 (v163). I also had an intermittent error on startup about a "Load error: undefined path variables" with a cryptic variable name.

After countless attempts at most solutions presented here (reimport the project, invalidate caches & restart, checks of project structure and paths...), the only thing that worked was to completely reinstall Intellij (removing the ~/.idea* ~/.IntellijIdea*) and selecting "No" at the question "would you like to migrate previous settings".

This finally worked.

Answer (score 3):

OS:Mac && IDE: IntelliJ && Project: Maven build

1. Navigate to File>Project Structure>Modules.
2. In right-hand area; list of modules would be present.
3. Delete the default one selected and close IntelliJ.
4. Next Open again; IntelliJ will ask if you want to treat the project
   as Maven project.
5. Accept that popup and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Intellij imports the project after resolving all the dependencies. In my case, it was unable to resolve dependencies for some of the modules and was stuck there. I had to copy my Maven `settings.xml` from local repo to the default `.m2` folder in order to point it to the correct local repo.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this answer for completeness. I was using 15.0.6 and had this problem. I trued to import a module from Maven or Gradle an it went through the process, but the module did not appear. I tried deleting the .idea file and restarting. Uninstalling and installing the latest version (community 2016.2) addressed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Select the module settings and do these changes, it will work

In File > Project Structure > Modules, click the "+" button,

add new module as per your project specific like Java or RUBY or something 
then apply and ok

Answer (score 2):

As I had the same issue and none of the above worked for me, this is what I did! I know it is a grumpy solution but at least it finally worked! I am not sure why only this method worked. It should be some weird cache in my PC?

1. I did close IntelliJ
2. I did completely remove the `.idea` folder from my project
3. I did move the folder `demo-project` to `demo-project-temp`
4. I did create a new empty folder `demo-project`
5. I did open this empty folder with intelliJ
6. I did move all the content `demo-project-temp`. Don't forget to also move the hidden files
7. Press right click "Synchronize" to your project
8. You should see all the files and folders now!
9. Now you can also safely remove the folder `demo-project-temp`. If you are on linux or MAC do it with `rmdir demo-project-temp` just to make sure that your folder is empty

Answer (score 2):

For me, it happens when i set `Project SDK` as JAVA SDK 14 in a react-native project. Upon unset, all the folders show up again.

Comment: Thank you! For me it turns out that WebOS SDK update (which included java) was the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Project Structure => Modules => Select your module => Paths => Make sure "Inherit project compile output path" is selected

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with an SBT project in IntelliJ 2016.2 after removing a globally installed IntelliJ and re-installing in my own home folder (Linux). No files or folders were shown in Project View anymore.

The Project Structure view wouldn't even open, and renaming the `.idea` folder to `.idea.bak` and re-importing the project didn't make any difference.

However, what fixed it for me was to reboot Linux. Afterwards it worked again, even with the original `.idea` folder. Seems this "fix" is not only restricted to the Windows world.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a gradle module with the same name as your projects root folder, the gradle import will replace your toplevel module configuration and change your view completely.

Make sure you have no gradle module with the same name as your root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when the .idea folder was accidentally added to SVN version control.  When I took an update --- blooey!   I subsequently removed the .idea folder from version control.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried all the solutions above, nothing worked.**

---

***Java-Maven project***

*My problem:* 
In my case i had java-maven project. And the problem was that Idea by default uses it's bundled maven for projects(or anyone you trying to open). 
I noticed that bundled maven keeps downloading dependencies forever, i.e you never see your sources folder.

*Solution:*
So to configure that, one needs to configure Idea to use maven(mvn) which is installed on the machine for all projects by default.
To do that, in the beginning when Idea still did not open any projects...there is a configure button. There chose build tools. Then maven, there you will see dropdown list where you can choose local maven.
In short: `Configure/Build Tools/Maven/DropdownMenu` 
(My OS: linux branch)

Hope that helps

Comment: In my case it worked (WebStorm)
FIle -> Repaire IDE  -> Rescan project indexes

Answer (score 1):

I have that little while earlier and solved it by following the steps provided below:

1. Right-click on the **External Libraries** and select the **Load/ Unload modules** button

[image]

2. If you see the modules are already loaded, perform the **unload/load** again as this happens due to a bug in the IntelliJ.

[image]

After I have done that, I see the project again at the top of the **External Libraries** section.

Answer (score 1):

For me in IntelliJ it was showing me a popup to import the existing project as gradle project. I just clicked ok on it and then the folder structure appeared properly.

Answer (score 1):

When importing your project/module be sure to check these two boxes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to open a scala/sbt project, the sbt version set in `/project/build.properties` must match the sbt version installed on your system or intellij won't detect your project's modules properly.

Once that's done, you can just delete the `idea` folder and restart as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable all plugins
2. Restart IDE
3. Files and folders should now be visible
4. Go through your plugins 1 by 1 enabling them to find the culprit

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this problem without having to delete the `.idea` folder (and thus having to re-configure the workspace), in WebStorm, but I assume it's going to be the same for IntelliJ and other JetBrains IDEs.

First, close your IDE and backup the `.idea` folder.

In `.idea` folder there should be `.iml` file with the name of your project. In my case it's `ClientApp.iml`. This file defines, which directories belong to the project, which should be excluded etc. Note the name of this file in your `.idea` folder.

Next, open `modules.xml` file. It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/ClientApp.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/ClientApp.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

Check if `fileurl` and `filepath` match name of your `.iml` file, if not fix the filenames, save and re-open your IDE. For me, this fixed it.

People in other answers are right that this is a problem with *Modules*. In WebStorm in 2024, there are no modules in Settings, I think it was renamed to *Directories*. When I added the project root this way, the project got renamed and all folder settings (test, resources, excluded) were lost, so fixing the `.xml` file seems like a better option.