# IDEA: How do I see subdirectories in an empty project?

Tags: intellij-idea

I wish to use IDEA to edit a directory full of files of no particular type. So, I create a new project of type **Empty Project** and point it at my directory.

The project view now shows the files in the directory itself. But, it doesn't show any subdirectories. This is very strange.

Even more strangely, I can still use **New -> Directory** to create a new directory. From the command line I can see that the directory has been created; but, from within IDEA, it's still not appearing.

What's going on here? And, more importantly, how can I actually get it to show me my subdirectories?

This is IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.1. I did find [IntelliJ does not show project folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816419/intellij-does-not-show-project-folders), which sounds similar. But, it is referring to a different version of IDEA and they're not using an Empty Project. So, I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: Add a module (for example web module) with the content root set to the project root.

Comment: Given that I can see the _files_ in the project root without a module, that shouldn't be necessary, surely? (Besides, there is no 'Empty Module' type...)

Comment: It's necessary. Files in the root is a special case, for the directories you have to add a module.

Comment: But why is it necessary? It seems like a very arbitrary limitation. I've created an empty project to make a simple high-fidelity mock-up. It isn't obvious or intuitive that I need a module.

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ, you have to create at least one module. As [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) said in the comments, adding a module sets the root folder of what to display in the **Project** pane.

Here are steps that I took to show empty folders.

In a terminal window

```
mkdir one
mkdir one/two
mkdir one/two/three
mkdir one/two/three/four
```

In Intellij 15.0.2, I created a new project, selected **Empty Project** and set the **Project Location** to the `one` folder.

After creating the project, IntelliJ prompts me with a **Project Structure** dialog with **Modules** selected in the navigation tree. I clicked the '+' button in the middle pane to add a module. I chose **Static Web** as the module type to prevent creation of an additional `src` folder. I set the **Content root** and the **Module file location** of the module to the same `one` folder.

[image: add module]

I clicked **Finish** and then **Ok**. This gave me this structure

[image: project structure]