# IntelliJ IDEA not showing my module/project

Tags: intellij-idea, project, project-management, setup-project, intellij-13

Suddenly, IntelliJ IDEA is showing the following module view with a strange yellow colour in the background. I don't know how to get my module back, because it is not being shown: [image]

Do you know how can I see my project folder back?

Thanks

Comment: Did you open the wrong intellij file? In "file-based" projects, there is the .ipr, .iml, .iws files. If you open the wrong one I can imagine it looks like that...

Comment: Could you please tell me how to browse through them? Not sure if I am understanding. Thanks

Comment: Okay, look in the folder where you created the project. Does it have an `.idea` folder (directory based), or can you see files ending with .ipr / .iws / .iml (file based) ? If it is the latter case you can incorrectly open the wrong file, I believe.

Comment: Thanks. It has an .idea folder

Comment: Hmm, ok, I dont see what can be wrong. Is it a problem there is no java code in your project? Maybe check the facets - should there be a web facet for example? Sorry, I'm out of ideas :)

Comment: No worries mate, I'll try it. I'll upvote you if I had just one more reputation point (I only have 14 and I need 15 :-( )

Comment: This link is useful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816419/intellij-does-not-show-project-folders

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can go to File-> Project Structure and then define it as a `Source Folder`

Answer (score 66):

This is way late, but deleting my `.idea` folder did the trick.

1. Close IntelliJ
2. `cd <project-path>`
3. `rm -rf .idea`

Comment: This worked for me in 2022. Invalidated cache and restarted Intellij because of unrelated reasons. SDK became unlinked as a result. Then the module structure became messed up. I deleted the module and tried to re-import from Maven. It just would not import. Finally doing this imported my module again with Maven. Had to manually re-define the SDK. And now looks like I'm back to normal. Intellij is known  to cause real headaches from time to time.

Comment: This is the last thing you can try, but before that try other options, in my case this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76578090/12715463 solved my issue

Comment: I was worried it'd hose IntelliJ even more, but it did the trick and appears to have fixed everything.

Answer (score 15):

In Intellij, Right click on your parent pom file and click add as maven project

Answer (score 6):

For Maven Projects that don't show up you can right click your pom.xml and click 'Add as Maven Project'.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on pom.xml -> Maven -> Reload Project

Comment: this worked for me and I had to do this for ALL of the modules in my project

Answer (score 2):

In my case Modules kept on disappearing and I managed to fix it with these simple steps:

- In the Project panel, right click to see the context menu
- Select "Open Module Settings"
- Select the Module that is not shown in the tree view
- Select the first tab labeled "Sources"
- Press the "+ Add Content Root" link
- Select the root folder where the files for this module are located

Once the folder has been scanned, press the OK button and you will see the Module appear

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Other answers did not solve the problem for me.

I ended up uninstalling IntelliJ, then installing a new copy. When prompted to import previous settings, I selected the option of not to import, then set up IntelliJ from scratch. After re-install/re-setup, I was able to open my project folder and all of the modules showed like before. Some how my IntelliJ got fubared, my guess is that it happened when I updated it last week.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I must've deleted my .iml file somehow. Files with .iml contain configuration for your modules. The problem was that my project module was not being loaded without it. I'm using gradle, syncing my project with gradle regenerated whichever *.iml was necessary to build. Here is a post that provides a succinct explanation. 
[IntelliJ IDE | .iml File lost or deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542288/intellij-ide-iml-file-lost-or-deleted)
Also - I know this issue is probably long gone and out of his head but for whoever may come across this issue, the above was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

***Check if the FACETS panel is blank***
[image]

If it's blank .Then click the "+" button to add
one.

For me .I need a android facet.
[image]

For details.go to this [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206891625--No-Module-when-setting-run-configuration-?page=1#community_comment_360000449979)

Hope this is work for you.

Answer (score -2):

I assume you are used to working with Eclipse. Intellij IDEA uses the same idea, but different names.

A Eclipse workspace is equal to IDEA's project.

A Eclipse project is equal to IDEA's module.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not an answer to my question.

Comment: What I mean is, point the IDEA project folder to your Eclipse workspace folder. Then you might need to set-up IDEA modules to compile and build.

Comment: I am not using Eclipse, thus I don't have the workspace folder you're referring to.

Comment: Could it be that the IDE project folder is pointed to your module folder?

Comment: Thanks. Could be; how can I check it out?

Comment: I have little experience with Intellij IDEA, but Android Studio is based on that, so I'll talk about that.

What I did was removing the project from the IDE and re-insert it into the IDE through the project file.

Comment: Thanks man, I think is a problem with the module, I will get rid of everything and config it again.