# PyCharm 2021.1.1 : Cannot load settings from file error

Tags: python, pycharm, configuration-files

Whenever I open PyCharm I get 2 warnings as marked with red in the image below :

[image]

The warnings are :

> **Load Settings**
>
> Cannot load settings from file 'F:\Restframework\ .idea\Restframework.iml':File F:\Restframework.idea\Restframework.iml does not exist Please correct the file content

and

> **Load Settings**
>
> Cannot load settings from file 'P:\Website Codes\Restframework\ .idea\Restframework.iml':File P:\Website Codes\Restframework.idea\Restframework.iml does not exist Please correct the file content

I don't have any `F:` drive in my laptop and in `Website Codes` folder in `P:` drive there is no `Restframework` folder. So , why I'm getting such warnings and what I'm supposed to do to avoid these warnings ??

Comment: I'm answering this question because the error message [Cannot load settings from file error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+%22Cannot+load+settings+from+file%22) doesn't currently have hits on SO's PyCharm tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

> Load Settings
>
> Cannot load settings from file (...)

is saying that the projects cannot be found at the paths specified in the settings files in [each project's `.idea` folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-up-your-project.html#storage). (This can happen for lots of reasons, the project files were moved, the drive letter changed, the `.idea` folder was copied from computer to another that has different paths, etc...)

Before solving the problem it's important to understand how projects work in PyCharm. **Each project is defined by having 1 `.idea` folder** (as explained in the above link). But you can [open multiple projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/open-projects.html#d9b204f2) in one window using "Attach Project" which causes 1 entry in the 1st project's [`workspace.xml`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-up-your-project.html#storage) file to each attached project (take notice that each individual project still has its own `.idea` folder with its own setting files in it).

You can fix this in several ways. First try to [Delete a project from view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/open-projects.html#delete-from-view) to get rid of the projects that might be causing the error, this removes references to "Attached Projects" from the 1st project.

If afterwards there are still projects causing these errors you can try to fix the [settings files of each individual project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-up-your-project.html#storage). One way of doing this is deleting the `.idea` folder in each project and reopening the project so PyCharm recreates the folder (backup the folder before deleting). You can also try to open the settings files and try to fix the paths inside them (this is a more complicated solution that requires being able to understand the contents of the settings files).

Comment: A lot of solutions to this and similar problems suggest deleting the .idea folder. The problem is that the .idea folder contains valuable data, such as Python run configurations, which should also be in GIT, so just deleting it is not always an option.

Comment: @FlorianWinter yes that's why this answer takes the methodical approach of reopening the project (there can be several in one window) or fixing the configuration files before recommending deletion (and advising to make a backup for reference). I've written several answers on editing the configuration files manually, but that depends on project specifics. The OP didn't post the configuration files so writing an answer on how to fix them wasn't doable.

Comment: @FlorianWinter As for committing run configurations to git most developers would recommend excluding them.