# Nothing to show in project view in Intellij Idea even though the src files are open in editor

Tags: intellij-idea

I was working on a `maven` project in Intellij Idea and suddenly the project view was gone with a spinning circle at the top right corner with showing the following message at the center of the project view

> Nothing to show

As you can see in the image the source codes are still visible. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359018/cant-see-project-folders-in-intellij-idea) is asked earlier but in it the reporter was able to see the files at the root of the project and was unable to see the folders in the root of the project. Since I can't see anything I think this is not the same. Is there a way to get it back to normal without restarting the Idea.[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't see project folders in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359018/cant-see-project-folders-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: There is some process going on or an exception, try getting the logs and the thread dumps: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544899. See if reinstalling helps, see if deleting third-party plugins helps (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519). Try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: @CrazyCoder just restarting IDEA fixed the issue, is there any other way to fix this without restarting IDEA?

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Yes, report the bug with the logs so that the developers can fix it.