# How to open project tree structure on left side in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I can not project tree structure on left side in Intellij IDEA following as image.

I can see only breadcrumb structure.
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Ctrl+1. This should open the first tab named "Project" on the left that is located right above "Structure" tab.

Comment: It is "alt+1" for me. We might have different key bindings.

Comment: when i click on "1: Project", Only ".gitignor",".svnignore","pom.xml","Readme.md" just look

Comment: @AhmetHakanBillur Try adding a module. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816419/intellij-does-not-show-project-folders

Comment: This just opens the project but doesn't solve the original issue

Answer (score 2):

Under C:\ click on "1: Project".

Comment: when i click on "1: Project", Only ".gitignor",".svnignore","pom.xml","Readme.md" just look

Comment: @AhmetHakanBillur Try adding your project as a module. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816419/intellij-does-not-show-project-folders

Answer (score 1):

You have "Structure" selected. Select "Project" instead. Just click here:

Based on your comments, you didn't import a Maven project right. Just go to *File -> Open* and point to `pom.xml`, *not* the folder. This will import the Maven structure correctly.

[image]

Comment: when i click on "1: Project", Only ".gitignor",".svnignore","pom.xml","Readme.md" just look

Comment: @AhmetHakanBillur Where would I _just look_? Anyway, this means you didn't open the project right. Just go to _File-> Open_ and point to pom.xml, not folder. This will import the Maven structure correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to go to your Project Path in your Machine and delete the .idea folder.

Next come back to IntelliJ and open the same project from IntelliJ under Files->Open (Dont use OpenRecent Tab)