# IntelliJ idea stucked on "loading project" screen

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

This is a Monday morning nightmare on top of existing bugs I have!!

I have couple of projects which i open simultaneously using intellj. One of the project was not showing all directory structures inside it so i [took some advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31227017/3154233) and deleted the `.idea` folder. Now all hell broke loose on me.

I am stucked here from the dawn of mankind now

[image]

Intellij logs

```
2017-12-04 09:46:59,444 [   9036]   INFO -                git4idea.GitVcs - Git version: 2.14.3.0 
2017-12-04 09:46:59,533 [   9125]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [/codebase/plutus] 
2017-12-04 09:47:01,309 [  10901]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 6353 ms 
2017-12-04 09:47:02,913 [  12505]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 4772ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 2/5 sluggish, 1/5 very slow 
2017-12-04 09:47:05,252 [  14844]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 18 project components initialized in 52 ms 

# ----- ^^ all good till here, below is when i start open new project


2017-12-04 09:47:26,455 [  36047]   INFO - og4jmonitor.Log4JWindowManager - creating new LoggingReceiver on port:=4454 
2017-12-04 09:47:26,496 [  36088]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 153 project components initialized in 165 ms 
2017-12-04 09:47:26,497 [  36089]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2017-12-04 09:47:26,645 [  36237]   INFO - CompilerBackwardReferenceIndex - backward reference index version differ due to: class java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Two errors i see on my screen are :

[image]

Intellij version

[image]

Any help would draw your chances of not having monday morning blues and nightmare like me! :) 
Thank you!

Comment: disable  Log4JPlugin?

Comment: its a quick hack but would bite-back in overall development!

Comment: then fix the plugin.

Comment: mmm....is that a sarcasm or am i not understanding something? how to fix? :)

Comment: You know, by programming... Or just ask the author?

Comment: hmmm......harsh *sarcasm*..got it...thanks! :)

Comment: No sarcasm, just common sense.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**[from comments]** 
**Warning:** While it works, if you invalidate the cache, it destroys all histories of all projects

---

So apparently, solution was simple but difficult to find.Here is how it worked :

1. close all projects in intellij, don't close IDE, just all projects.
2. delete the `.idea/` folder from the project which was getting stucked.
3. open the same project in intellij
4. do `File` -> `invalidate caches and restart`
5. done

Comment: Warning: While it works, if you invalidate the cache, it destroys all histories of all projects.

Comment: its a known hazard! :)

Comment: Closing all open projects worked for me! Then I was able to load components for the newly created project.

Answer (score 11):

Delete the `.idea` folder from project worked for me.

Comment: Helped too but have to make all settings again.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's because of Log4JPlugin see - [problem here also](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207026405/comments/203695784) 
in my case : delete this(Log4JPlugin) plugin and restart it -> it's worked for me

Comment: I had a similar issue, but with the ANTLR plugin. Upvoting this because a bad plugin can cause a hang. Disabling it fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

I had red icon in the corner. Clicking it showed information of some problem with Makefile support. I disable the plugin and all opened as usual.

==> Glady I didn't delete the .idea folder as suggested (I just renamed it, and renamted back after solving the problem). Delete it will also cause losing deployment server info and probably more other important date.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by deleting only the file `workspace.xml` located under `.idea` folder. 
This is useful whenever you need to keep configs of your plugins for that project.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a partly-completed `Resolve Conflicts`.

Complete the conflict resolution using a different tool before opening the project again.

Answer (score 1):

- Close all opened projects to startup PhpStorm window
- Open folder/project that you need
- Profit

Comment: What's `PhpStorm` doing here?

Comment: IntelliJ idea and PhpStorm in general have the same code, so some problems like described, fixed in the same way. 
I had an issue with PhpStorm, so I described it here. I'm sure that this solution will help.

Answer (score 1):

Mine had the biggest stack trace I have ever seen in the logs:  1025 lines.

The skinny was I had just done some Maven Archetype work and enabled the plugin.  When I found this stack trace, I disabled it and it worked fine.

```
   Conflicting component name 'Archetypes.Configuration': class org.google.code.archetypes.ArchetypesConfiguration and class org.google.code.archetypes.ArchetypesConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

I had set the runtime version to java 8 instead of java 11 using the `choose runtime` plugin (for version 2020.2). Reverted it back to 11, invalidated caches and restarted, and the problem went away. (When I had this problem, wasn't able to open action pop up, so assigned a shortcut to `choose runtime` from preferences.)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I used guidance [from JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008135799-IntelliJ-Idea-Hangs-When-Starting).

Remove the configuration folder.
**macOS**:
*Configuration (idea.config.path): ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3

Plugins (idea.plugins.path): ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/plugins*

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ keeps its data in the `.idea` folder. Deleting `.idea` folder from the project repo and re-opening the project should fix this issue (worked for me).

Answer (score 1):

I am working with the IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Community Edition). The project was stack at the loading screen. Cancelling the event would freeze the whole IntelliJ.

The solution that worked for me was to delete the .iml and .ipr files. After that the project loaded as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When the "loading..." appears. Try to save a file. That seems to trigger a event to the file-system, and the directory is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

disabling Eclipse PDE Partial plugin solved for me on an OSGi project.
I encountered this issue on IntelliJ Idea 2022.2.2 Build #IC-222.4167.29 Community Edition.

Of course I had to delete the .idea directory and reimport the project as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47666733/528074).