# IntelliJ idea does not properly see modules of generated Ktor project. Android Studio does see them

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, module, ktor, project-structure

###### .0. I imported a project to the PC (specifically here =  generated Ktor project, although I've seen such behavior before with Compose Desktop projects)

[Generated here](https://start.ktor.io/#/settings?name=ktor-sample&website=example.com&artifact=com.example.ktor-sample&kotlinVersion=1.8.10&ktorVersion=2.2.3&buildSystem=GRADLE_KTS&engine=NETTY&configurationIn=HOCON&addSampleCode=true&plugins=)

###### .1. IntelliJ Idea doesn't recognize it as a project

[image]

When I open the same project on Android Studio = it works fine
[image]

Here is how the project supposed to look in IntelliJ (this Ktor project I build manually with IDE and it worked):

[image]

###### .2. I was able to make the project folders visible to IDE:

Repair IDE->Rescan Project Indexes->Reopen Project

[image]

Now It look like this:

[image]

###### But IDE still doesn't see my modules properly

[image]

[image]

How do I properly configure the imported project?

Note: I've read [IntelliJ does not show project folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816419/intellij-does-not-show-project-folders)
And tried methods described there. But a lot of answers are hard to replicate as IntelliJ interface changed.

Edit: I've fixed it with Manage Idea Settings->Restore Default Settings. Now projects are opened properly. Thank everyone for your time.

Comment: Can you try to right-click on the `build.gradle.kts` or `settings.gradle.kts` file and choose `Link Gradle Project`?

Comment: I've just tried to `Link Gradle Project`,  and I got the message Project Reload Failed (The project is already registered)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem with Manage Idea Settings->Restore Default Settings. Now projects are opened properly. Thank everyone for your time.

[image]